# Don't pin jms groups to specific worker

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, hornetq

Updated:

We receive measurement values from different measurement stations, and put them for processing into a jms queue.
Now we use jms grouping, where the groupId is the id of the station, to ensure that the values from one station are processed serially.

Just see the stock sample in the docs: http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.2.Final/user-manual/en/html/message-grouping.html

But in HornetQ (or jms at all), each group is pinned to one specific worker. This means if group A and group B are pinned to Worker X and there are 10 Messages for group A and 10 messages for group B in the queue, the group B messages have to wait until the group A messages are handled. (Although there are enough free workers, that can handle the group B messages right now)

Is there a way, to tell jms, not to pin each group to one specific worker, but only to ensure the serial processomg within each group.

Answer (score 0):

JMS queues do prevent parallel processing. Have you confirmed that the different consumers process the same message? Does each message have a unique ID and are you logging the ID of each message processed?

From the example you gave it sounds like you are mis-using JMS queues. Could you update your question with a clearer, more in-depth example of your workflow?

Right now with the way your question is worded, it sounds like you need to re-design your workflow model